Jupyter (lab and notebook) indentation invisible and unusable
Notebook version 7.2.2

The white space is invisible in the editor - spaces and tabs are invisible.
How do I set the spaces to be seen as dots .   and the tabs to be seen as arrows ?

The indentation used by editor seems to change.  One minute it is inserting tabs, the next it is indenting with spaces.
How do I set the editor to specifically use tabs for indentation?


I have tried the editor settings as stated in various posts, to no avail.
Not being able to see the white space characters makes the problem worse.
Jupyter is unusable if I have to copy and paste each block into a separate text editor to be able to edit it, and then have to copy it back to run it.
Python scripts are absolutely dependent on white space indentation. It seems incredible that a python editor would not have the ability to make white space visible built-in.
Can anyone help?
